# Avoiding Data Redundancy

Tags: php, html, sql

I am working on a code for my music site. This is part of the registration phase. I want the code to check the database for any existing email addresses, if found, print " email ("email address") already exists, but if not found, then insert the information into the database. The code seems to run if an email address similar to the one submitted from the html form is found, but if there is no email found, the system stops and does nothing after that. Can someone help me figure out where i went wrong.

```
if ($_POST['submit2']){ 
$fname = $_POST['Fname'];
$sname = $_POST['Sname'];
$email = $_POST['Emailaddress'];
$pass = $_POST['newpassword'];

$sql= "select * from cust_information where email = '$email';";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if (count($row) < 0)
    {
        $sql2 = "insert into cust_information (firstName, lastName, email, password) values(`$fname`, `$sname`, `$email`, `$pass`)";
         $results2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
         if (!$results2){
         echo "successfully uploaded cust";
        }   
    }else{
         echo "email <strong>".$row["email"]. " </strong> already Exist";
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is wide open to SQL injection, however to fix your bug try to use `'$fname'` quotes, backtics are used to quote table and field names, not strings.

Comment: @Banelegumata You're checking if `count` returns an integer less than zero.  This is impossible, and the code within will never execute.

Comment: doesnt work... the fields are not added onto the db. ill work on the SQL injection as soon as im done with sorting out this issue.

Comment: @daedalus okay i get that, should i try checking if count is greater than 0?

Comment: @Banelegumata If you're checking for the non-existence of a row, make sure the count is equatable to 0.  Not less, not more.

Comment: You can also use [$results->num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead of the count function. So the correct way would be `if ($results->num_rows === 0)` instead of `if (count($row) < 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking whether the number of results returned is less than 0. The length of an array (and the number of results found) cannot ever be less than 0. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) shows that `mysqli_fetch_array` returns `null` if no results are found, thus you want to check for `$row === null`.

However, I will take this opportunity to point out that concatenating variables into a SQL query string leaves you wide open to a serious security concern called [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). As the code is currently set up, users of the form will be able to run any query they like on your database which is absolutely not what you want. I recommend reading up on [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to mitigate this problem.